# Tweening Functions in CreateJS

Tags: javascript, createjs, tween

I'm working on a **createjs** game where an image is held inside of a container. I want to tween the image to a location on the screen and switch the image to another image. After a number of seconds pass, I want to remove the new image from the canvas/screen.

Currently, I'm passing an (evt) into the function, but the other games/examples all don't bother with this part?

It works in the first .call function, but the part where I commented out after the .wait and the second .call does not work.  Suddenly, `TheThingBeingTweened` is `undefined`?

Any tip in the right direction should be helpful.

```
createjs.Tween
        .get(inkContainer, {onChange: onInkContainerTweenChange})
        .to({
                 y: playerContainer.y + (Math.random() * 200 - 100),
                 x: playerContainer.x + (Math.random() * 200)
            }, 8000)
        .call(function (evt) {
    var theThingBeingTweened = evt.target;

    //self.stage.removeChild(theThingBeingTweened);

    var theContainer = theThingBeingTweened.parent;
    theContainer.removeChild(theThingBeingTweened);

    splatContainer = new createjs.Container();
    splat = new 
    createjs.Bitmap(queue.getResult("splat"));
    splatContainer.addChild(splat);
    splatContainer.x = theThingBeingTweened.x;
    splatContainer.y = theThingBeingTweened.y;
    theContainer.addChild(splatContainer);
});

//.wait(3000)
//.call(function (evt) {
//    var theThingBeingTweened = evt.target;
//    self.stage.removeChild(theThingBeingTweened);
//});
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can expand your object by overwriting or adding a property

For example:

```
// It coud be instance or singleton it can knows everything to handle your issue
var imageHandler = new ImageHandlerClass();

Object.defineProperty(inkContainer, "imageHandler", { value:imageHandler , configurable: true, writable: true, enumerable: true });

createjs.Tween
        .get(inkContainer)
        .to({
                 y: playerContainer.y + (Math.random() * 200 - 100),
                 x: playerContainer.x + (Math.random() * 200)
            }, 8000)
        .call(function (evt) {
             var linkToImageHandler = evt.target.imageHandler;
            // Do something with image using imageHandler defined erlier
            //...

        });
```

It is very useful when you have one events controller for many repetitive situations.

Answer (score 0):

While the exact reason why `theThingBeingTweened` is `undefined` is unclear, you can bypass this limitation easily by declaring `theThingBeingTweened` outside of the scope of your call chain, and then just don't re-initialize it with the `undefined` value in the second call.

```
var theThingBeingTweened;

createjs.Tween
        .get(inkContainer, {onChange: onInkContainerTweenChange})
        .to({
                 y: playerContainer.y + (Math.random() * 200 - 100),
                 x: playerContainer.x + (Math.random() * 200)
            }, 8000)
        .call(function (evt) {
    theThingBeingTweened = evt.target;

    //self.stage.removeChild(theThingBeingTweened);

    var theContainer = theThingBeingTweened.parent;
    theContainer.removeChild(theThingBeingTweened);

    splatContainer = new createjs.Container();
    splat = new 
    createjs.Bitmap(queue.getResult("splat"));
    splatContainer.addChild(splat);
    splatContainer.x = theThingBeingTweened.x;
    splatContainer.y = theThingBeingTweened.y;
    theContainer.addChild(splatContainer);
}).wait(3000).call(function (evt) {
    self.stage.removeChild(theThingBeingTweened);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `call` method does *not* result in a dispatched event. There is no `event` parameter, so there is no `event.target`.

Instead, you can pass parameters to the call method (2nd argument).

```
createjs.Tween
    .get(inkContainer, {onChange: onInkContainerTweenChange})
    .to({
             y: playerContainer.y + (Math.random() * 200 - 100),
             x: playerContainer.x + (Math.random() * 200)
        }, 8000)
    .call(function (thing) {
        // The thing being tweened is the first argument
    }, [inkContainer, otherArg], optionalScope);
```

Note that if it *was* an event, then the target would be the tween instance, not thing tween's target. This is the case when you use `addEventListener` or `on` for the supported events of Tweens (which is just "change").
http://www.createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/Tween.html#event_change